# yarn install command fails with error Expression form not supported

Tags: angular, angular-material, jhipster

I have developed an app with jhipster and trying to switch my app to production version, it fails on yarn install command with error code:

```
 Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Expression form not supported (position 29:10 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol ɵu in /home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts, resolving symbol _MdPseudoCheckboxBase in /home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts, resolving symbol MdPseudoCheckbox in /home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts
    at positionalError (/home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23471:35)
    at simplifyInContext (/home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23314:27)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (/home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23328:13)
    at StaticReflector.propMetadata (/home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:22812:56)
    at DirectiveResolver.resolve (/home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13053:73)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (/home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13766:64)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata (/home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13691:23)
    at /home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13915:54
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (/home/dmitrij/IdeaProjects/devizion/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13914:41)
Compilation failed
```

@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts is a pretty simple typescript file with nothing special in it.

```
/**
 * Generated bundle index. Do not edit.
 */
export * from './public_api';
export { mixinColor as ɵu } from './core/common-behaviors/color';
export { mixinDisabled as ɵv } from './core/common-behaviors/disabled';
export { UNIQUE_SELECTION_DISPATCHER_PROVIDER_FACTORY as ɵh } from './core/coordination/unique-selection-dispatcher';
export { MdDateFormats as ɵw } from './core/datetime/date-formats';
export { OVERLAY_CONTAINER_PROVIDER as ɵb, OVERLAY_CONTAINER_PROVIDER_FACTORY as ɵa } from './core/overlay/overlay-container';
export { OverlayPositionBuilder as ɵt } from './core/overlay/position/overlay-position-builder';
export { VIEWPORT_RULER_PROVIDER as ɵd, VIEWPORT_RULER_PROVIDER_FACTORY as ɵc } from './core/overlay/position/viewport-ruler';
export { SCROLL_DISPATCHER_PROVIDER as ɵf, SCROLL_DISPATCHER_PROVIDER_FACTORY as ɵe } from './core/overlay/scroll/scroll-dispatcher';
export { RippleRenderer as ɵg } from './core/ripple/ripple-renderer';
export { EXPANSION_PANEL_ANIMATION_TIMING as ɵi } from './expansion/expansion-panel';
export { MdGridAvatarCssMatStyler as ɵk, MdGridTileFooterCssMatStyler as ɵm, MdGridTileHeaderCssMatStyler as ɵl, MdGridTileText as ɵj } from './grid-list/grid-tile';
export { MdMenuItemBase as ɵn, _MdMenuItemMixinBase as ɵo } from './menu/menu-item';
export { MdPaginatorIntl as ɵx } from './paginator/paginator-intl';
export { MdTabBase as ɵr, _MdTabMixinBase as ɵs } from './tabs/tab';
export { MdTabLabelWrapperBase as ɵp, _MdTabLabelWrapperMixinBase as ɵq } from './tabs/tab-label-wrapper';
```

I really have no idea what could be the solution to this problem, maybe downgrading @angular/material to some earlier versions, but then to which one?

Comment: You should add some details like your package.json which contains all versions and by the way it's very unlikely a yarn issue, it's just that there is an install script which launches compilation that fails.

Comment: downgrading to the @angular/material@2.0.0.beta.2 solved the issue, well at least this one